# Mockito: Calling verify() with mocked arguments doesn't trigger a failure

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm doing some test-driven development and added a Mockito verify() call to my test case like so (names changed to protect the innocent code):

```
Api api = mock(Api.class);
Thing thing = mock(Thing.class);
when(thing.getId()).thenReturn(1);

// later...
verify(api).doAThingWithAThingId(thing.getId())
```

Even though I have not added the call `api.doAThingWithAThingId()` to my code, this test case passes! However, when I do this...

```
int id = thing.getId();
verify(api).doAThingWithAThingId(id);
```

the verification fails as expected. What is causing this behavior?

(For the record, this is using a slightly older version of Mockito, 1.8.4.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just run this with Mockito 1.9.5 and I can't reproduce the behaviour you've described.  But I believe I know why it might have happened with an older version.

Mockito has a "stubbing mode" and a "verification mode" that affect the behaviour of its mocks, and it switches between these modes as needed.  So when you write `verify`, Mockito switches into verify mode.  The next call to a method on a mock does a verify, instead of performing the stubbed action, but it also switches Mockito out of verify mode.

So when you write `verify(api).doAThingWithAThingId(thing.getId())`, Mockito 1.8.4 goes into verification mode; but the call to `thing.getId()` takes it OUT of `verify` mode.  Then the call to `doAThingWithAThingId` never actually gets verified.

The moral - in any version of Mockito, do NOT call any methods on mocks, in the arguments to a call following `verify`.  Evaluate the arguments that you need FIRST, before you start verifying.

Comment: Thanks for this short explanation. I’m often baffled by Mockito and ‘ongoing stubbing’.

Comment: Yeah, I _just_ verified, through a simple test, that this occurs with Mockito 1.8.*, but not in Mockito 1.9. Lesson learned!

Comment: As one more bit of info, this was actually a known defect that was fixed back in 1.8.5: https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=138

Comment: I am using mockito 1.9.5 and having the above defined issue.

I am calling a spy methods function and then verifying logs written by this method. I have inserted the Mocked Log with Reflection.

Comment: @RahulDabas It's impossible to know exactly what you're doing wrong, without seeing your code.  I'm sure that it's not the same issue, since using Mockito 1.9 fixed the issue for aarestad.  Perhaps you could post a new question, with your code included.  You should also point out that you've read this post, and that your question is not a duplicate since the cause of the problem is different.  But until I see your code, I really can't help you.